# Going about creating a 1x4 KeyBrick game

Tags: java

I need to make a button assigned to a random keystroke cause a button to disappear and cause another one to reappear with a random assigned keystroke again.

This is what I have so far:

This is my game start :

```
package code;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game implements Runnable{


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Game");
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setSize(500,200);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          frame.add(panel);
          JButton button = new JButton("Start The Game");
          panel.add(button);
         button.addActionListener (new StartButton(frame));
    }
}
```

This is my button layout where it's 1x4:

```
package code;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StartButton implements ActionListener {

private JFrame _j;
public StartButton(JFrame frame){
    _j = frame;
}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     

    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("ABC");


    frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame2.setSize(600,600);
    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Game");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame2.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);       
    _j.setVisible(false); //This creates a new game frame

    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,1);

            frame2.setLayout(experimentLayout);

            frame2.add(new JButton(""));
            frame2.add(new JButton(""));
            frame2.add(new JButton(""));
            frame2.add(new JButton(""));
}
}
```

Should I give the buttons their own variables?  How do I go about making a random key be shown and when its pressed it will delete that key and then cause a new button to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two things.

1. A KeyListener
2. A variable that holds the next key that needs to be pressed.

For the variable that holds the random key to be pressed I suggest putting all possible keys that can be pressed into an array and then using a randomly generated number to choose the from the array.

The KeyListener would simply need to check if the key that is pressed is the right key, if it is then it needs to create a new JButton somewhere on the screen and assign a new random keystroke (based on my suggestion from the array).

The JButton that is created each time the correct random key pressed should be put into a single variable (since you only ever need one of them) and each time you can just create a new JButton and put it in the variable. However a more effecient way would be to simply change the single JButtons position so you don't need to create a new object each time.

Keystrokes can be put into a variable using the KeyEvent class. For example `if (randomKey == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)` is true if the space bar gets pressed.

Comment: How do i make the new button appear?  Can you possibly write the code for the KeyListener?  I tried it but errors were upsetting.

Comment: To make it appear you add it to a JPanel (which is added to a JFrame). I'm not going to write the actual code because from my own experience the only way to remember how to do it is to make all the mistakes as frustrating as they are. This is a link to the java tutorial on KeyListeners: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: Still ever so lost :(.  Thanks for replying I guess

Comment: @AsifBhuiyan - hey, that's a good answer :) It's like a roadmap. Now take one step after the other. If you get stuck somewhere specific you can always ( after some research effort) ask a new detailed question.

Comment: I need to make the JButton show a random key from the alphabet.  Here is my code so far :

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
     String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
     JButton b = new JButton("myStringArray");
     JButton b2 = new JButton("");
     JButton b3 = new JButton("");
     JButton b4 = new JButton("");

Obviously its not showing the button as a random letter but rather just "myStringArray"  How do i go about doing so?

Comment: The issue is that you're not accessing the information inside the array. You would need to generate a random number (look into the class Random). and use that as the index. So you would do `JButton b = new JButton(myStringArray[randomNum]);`

Comment: When I do that it just gives me "a"

    private int randomNum;
    public StartButton(JFrame frame){
 _j = frame;
}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
 String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
 JButton b = new JButton(myStringArray[randomNum]);
 JButton b2 = new JButton(myStringArray[randomNum]);
 JButton b3 = new JButton(myStringArray[randomNum]);
 JButton b4 = new JButton(myStringArray[randomNum]);

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817283/how-to-make-one-actionperfomed-on-a-jbuttin-matrix-java/33817303#33817303